# Pick layout file from different-2 layout folders - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android App , Here Android App is not picking layout file from different -2 layout folders for different screens sizes . Here is the screen shot of layout folder structure which I am using .

[image]

I have tested the app for two devices having screen resolution **480 x 800** and **720 x 1280** , for both screens App is picking file from **layout-sw320dp** , and I aspect It should pic layout file from different layout folder .
I have visited [Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but no luck .

Comment: Screen resolution pixels are not the same as device independent pixels ("dp").  The multiple screen support page should make this clear.  If you're using dp size as the qualifier for layouts, you can't expect that to work with the same actual screen dimensions when the device density is not mdpi.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your comment . So what should I do to pick layout file from differnt-2 layout folders for different-2 screen sizes/desities ..